# Check if value exists in enum in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I receive a number `type = 3` and have to check if it exists in this enum:

```
export const MESSAGE_TYPE = {
    INFO: 1,
    SUCCESS: 2,
    WARNING: 3,
    ERROR: 4,
};
```

The best way I found is by getting all Enum Values as an array and using indexOf on it. But the resulting code isn't very legible:

```
if( -1 < _.values( MESSAGE_TYPE ).indexOf( _.toInteger( type ) ) ) {
    // do stuff ...
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: `if(Object.values(MESSAGE_TYPE).includes(+type)`? There's not much you can do.

Comment: This works in ES6 but not in ES5 unfortunately

Comment: @TimSchoch You can just do `!!MESSAGE_TYPE[type]`to check if a value exists. `MESSAGE_TYPE[type]` will return undefined if the value of `type` doesn't exist on `MESSAGE_TYPE`

Comment: @Kevin Babcock That will fail of one of the enum values maps to `0`, though.

Comment: @Ingo Bürk Great point! I guess an explicit check could be made `MESSAGE_TYPE[type] !== undefined`

Comment: Just don't use enums ...if possible.

Answer (score 626, accepted):

If you want this to work with string enums, you need to use `Object.values(ENUM).includes(ENUM.value)` because string enums are not reverse mapped, according to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums:

```
enum Vehicle {
    Car = 'car',
    Bike = 'bike',
    Truck = 'truck'
}
```

becomes:

```
{
    Car: 'car',
    Bike: 'bike',
    Truck: 'truck'
}
```

So you just need to do:

```
if (Object.values(Vehicle).includes('car')) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

If you get an error for: `Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'`, then you are not targeting ES2017. You can either use this tsconfig.json config:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"]
}
```

Or you can just do an any cast:

```
if ((<any>Object).values(Vehicle).includes('car')) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: JSONLint is showing `Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'`.

Comment: @BBaysinger in typescript try this instead: `(<any>Object).values(Vehicle).includes(Vehicle.car)`

Comment: Excellent. This should be the accepted answer. Accepted answer won't work if my enum keys and values are different

Comment: This does not work in typescript. Also the work around provided breaks in IE

Comment: @JerinJoseph which versions of IE didn't work, and what solution did work for you?

Comment: Xiv, maybe you could merge @Salem 's comment into your answer?

Comment: Better to use (Object as any).values(Enum).includes(Enum.value)

Comment: `error TS2345: Argument of type '"get"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Method'.

9 console.log(Object.values(Method).includes('get'));`

Comment: I believe that this is not an answer to this question. Your solution `(Object.values(Vehicle).includes(Vehicle.car))` will always be true, but the question is how check that a given value is included in enum, for example `(Object.values(Vehicle).includes('car'))` should return `true` but `(Object.values(Vehicle).includes('plane'))` should return false.

Comment: `Object.values(Vehicle).includes('car')` however warns `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Vehicle'` so you also have to type assert

Comment: @JHH I even have it as an error preventing compilation

Comment: Is this fine?

if (Object.values(Vehicle).includes('car' as any)) {
    // Do stuff here
}

Comment: @Aravin 's solution works and solves the bug mentioned by @ JHH

Comment: @JerinJoseph, unless you are unfortunately stuck supporting a legacy app for some company that refuses to upgrade, don't bother with IE anymore. Not even Microsoft is supporting it anymore.

Comment: `Object.values<string>(Enum).includes(value)` works for me

Comment: this implementation works in enzyme, when u unit tests, otherwise with for in, makes problem.

Comment: @JHH in Typescript one could use `Object.keys(Vehicle).includes('car')` as long as the key and value are same.

Comment: @EhteshamZ If keys and values are the same, `Vehicle['car']` also works, I believe.

Comment: This answer is outdated. TS 4.5 gives `TS2475: 'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query.`

Comment: Worked for me, but i had to use `Object.values(Vehicle).includes('car' as Vehicle)`

Comment: @AndyGarcia I think this is the best approach

Answer (score 346):

**This works only on non-const, number-based enums. For const enums or enums of other types, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755096/2419531)**

---

If you are using TypeScript, you can use an [actual enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). Then you can check it using `in`.

```
export enum MESSAGE_TYPE {
    INFO = 1,
    SUCCESS = 2,
    WARNING = 3,
    ERROR = 4,
};

var type = 3;

if (type in MESSAGE_TYPE) {

}
```

This works because when you compile the above enum, it generates the below object:

```
{
    '1': 'INFO',
    '2': 'SUCCESS',
    '3': 'WARNING',
    '4': 'ERROR',
    INFO: 1,
    SUCCESS: 2,
    WARNING: 3,
    ERROR: 4
}
```

Comment: this only works with proper enums, right? currently it is defined as such: `export const MESSAGE_TYPE = { ... }`

Comment: Yes. Only with proper enums.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. I'll check why we're not using a proper enum and see if we can change it.

Comment: We changed `MESSAGE_TYPE` to an actual enum as you suggested and now your solution works like a charm. Thanks @Saravana

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with `const` enums, so you lose the (slight) advantage of compile-time insertion.

Comment: This does not work with string enums because they are not reverse mapped:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html

Comment: It seems like this approach works with string enums in 2021.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: For string enums it only works if your enum keys are the same as values, e.g. enum Enum { foo = 'foo' }; But I wouldn't recommend relying on it in this case

Comment: @grumd I would absolutely recommend using the "same key as value" convention on enums. So in my case the in operator is the perfect tool.

Answer (score 146):

[According to sandersn](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33200#issuecomment-527670779) the best way to do this would be:

```
Object.values(MESSAGE_TYPE).includes(type as MESSAGE_TYPE)
```

Comment: This is probably the best and safest answer. It avoids the use of `any`. The `type in MESSAGE_TYPE` syntax might be better if you can guarantee that the key and the value of the enum will be the same since it's a key lookup rather than a value lookup.

Comment: aha! found way down in the answers, I can confirm this solution works without any `any` or type complains, AND it works when the enum names themselves do not match their respective actual values (as many hacky solutions on this page suggest or use). Should be the accepted answer, especially coming originally from TypeScript's GitHub.

Comment: This works for every case you need to check. Perfect answer.

Comment: this does not narrows the type, just returns a boolean

Comment: @Danielo515 Yes, you could replace the predicate in the `if` presented in the question with it. Do you have trouble using it?

Comment: Simple and concise, THIS is the right answer

Comment: And the winner is you. Perfet answer, thank you a lot !!!

Comment: Why do you use `str as any` instead of `str as MESSAGE_TYPE`?

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriadis It was an extra edit someone added to my answer, I reverted it to the original version.

Answer (score 41):

```
export enum YourEnum {
   enum1 = 'enum1',
   enum2 = 'enum2',
   enum3 = 'enum3',
}

const status = 'enumnumnum';

if (!Object.values(YourEnum)?.includes(status)) {
     throw new UnprocessableEntityResponse('Invalid enum val');
}
```

Comment: I like this the most

Comment: So this example is just using key==value and that's the reason it works, right? If key!=value, it would check by key.

Comment: Actually this case works only because of a coincident. 'enum1' would only be found because it's the same value as the key. But if the keys differ from the values it doesn't work.

Comment: @lukas_o is right about that. This solution looks clear at first glance but it is definitely bug-prone.

Comment: Yes this is a bad example and should not be used as is. The `in` keyword matches keys, not values, so you need a better solution for the if statement, such as `Object.values(YourEnum).includes(status)` or an indexOf solution for ES5.

Comment: I got a type error when using this naively, basically saying that string is not assignable to YourEnum. So I need to map the values using `.map(v => v.toString())` before checking for inclusion.

Answer (score 20):

There is a very simple and easy solution to your question:

```
var districtId = 210;

if (DistrictsEnum[districtId] != null) {

// Returns 'undefined' if the districtId not exists in the DistrictsEnum 
    model.handlingDistrictId = districtId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ester for your answer. Since I've moved from programming to fulltime UX Design I can't verify this anymore. @crowd, let me know if I the accepted answer is still the way to go in 2019! Cheers

Comment: @TimSchoch I can confirm this works very well at least for numeric enums. This is the most elegant solution imho.

Comment: @PatrickP. can you confirm that the solution proposed by Ester works for string enums too?

Comment: @TimSchoch Yes! It works for strings too. like a Dictionary - you can use any type for the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Keep in mind this solution is prone of false positives as well when the enum is numeric because the object created by Typescript has keys mapping in both directions. In the original example MESSAGE_TYPE['INFO'] === 1 and MESSAGE_TYPE['1'] === 'INFO'

Comment: Note that this does NOT work for string enums if the enum uses string initializers with different values than the enum member names. See @Xiv's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755096/4752920

Comment: This don't work for string. If your string is like `"to_delete"`, typescript transform it into camelcase. So the key is `"toDelete"` and not `"to_delete"`, like `{toDelete: 'to_delete'}`

Answer (score 19):

Type assertion is un-avoidable. Following up on

```
enum Vehicle {
    Car = 'car',
    Bike = 'bike',
    Truck = 'truck'
}
```

I found one alternative that wasn't mentioned so thought I'd share my fix for it:

```
const someString: Vehicle | string = 'car';
const inEnum = (Object.values(Vehicle) as string[]).includes(someString);
```

I find this more truthful because we usually come in typesafe(with a string) and want to compare it to the enum; it'd be a bit reckless to typecast it to `any`(reason: never do this) or `Vehicle`(reason: likely untruthful). Instead, typecasting the `Object.values()` output to an array of strings is in-fact very much real.

Comment: I like to use two lines:
    const options: string[] = Object.values(TheEnum);
    const isInTheEnum = options.includes(theValue);

Comment: I think this one is the most readable. This is what I ended up using.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Agree with @jcollum, it's the most readable and most truthful

Answer (score 10):

```
export enum UserLevel {
  Staff = 0,
  Leader,
  Manager,
}

export enum Gender {
  None = "none",
  Male = "male",
  Female = "female",
}
```

Difference result in log:

```
log(Object.keys(Gender))
=>
[ 'None', 'Male', 'Female' ]

log(Object.keys(UserLevel))
=>
[ '0', '1', '2', 'Staff', 'Leader', 'Manager' ]
```

The solution, we need to remove key as a number.

```
export class Util {
  static existValueInEnum(type: any, value: any): boolean {
    return Object.keys(type).filter(k => isNaN(Number(k))).filter(k => type[k] === value).length > 0;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
// For string value
if (!Util.existValueInEnum(Gender, "XYZ")) {
  //todo
}

//For number value, remember cast to Number using Number(val)
if (!Util.existValueInEnum(UserLevel, 0)) {
  //todo
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who comes here looking to validate if a string is one of the values of an enum and type convert it, I wrote this function that returns the proper type and returns `undefined` if the string is not in the enum.

```
function keepIfInEnum<T>(
  value: string,
  enumObject: { [key: string]: T }
) {
  if (Object.values(enumObject).includes((value as unknown) as T)) {
    return (value as unknown) as T;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

As an example:

```
enum StringEnum {
  value1 = 'FirstValue',
  value2 = 'SecondValue',
}
keepIfInEnum<StringEnum>('FirstValue', StringEnum)  // 'FirstValue'
keepIfInEnum<StringEnum>('OtherValue', StringEnum)  // undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Update:

I've found that whenever I need to check if a value exists in an enum, I don't really need an enum and that a type is a better solution. So my enum in my original answer becomes:

```
export type ValidColors =
  | "red"
  | "orange"
  | "yellow"
  | "green"
  | "blue"
  | "purple";
```

#### Original answer:

For clarity, I like to break the `values` and `includes` calls onto separate lines. Here's an example:

```
export enum ValidColors {
  Red = "red",
  Orange = "orange",
  Yellow = "yellow",
  Green = "green",
  Blue = "blue",
  Purple = "purple",
}

function isValidColor(color: string): boolean {
  const options: string[] = Object.values(ValidColors);
  return options.includes(color);
}
```

Comment: The problem with `type ValidColors` is that you can't write an `isValidColor(color: string): boolean` function for it: since `type ValidColors` doesn't exist at runtime, there is nothing to check against. This is a problem if you're trying to go from an un-typed API (e.g. user input) to a `ValidColor` and reject invalid inputs.

Comment: @mamacdon, absolutely. That's why I left my original answer as well. I've just noticed that most often, when I'm reaching for an enum, it's in situations where I'm validating things like Vue component properties, and in those cases, a type works.

Answer (score 1):

The following function returns another function which acts as a type predicate for the input enum (assuming it is a string style enum).

```
function constructEnumPredicate<RuntimeT extends string, EnumClass extends {[key: string]: RuntimeT}>(enumClass: EnumClass): (maybeEnum: string) => maybeEnum is EnumClass[keyof EnumClass] {
    const reverseMapping: {[key: string]: boolean} = {};

    for (const enumVal in enumClass) {
        const enumStr = enumClass[enumVal];
        reverseMapping[enumStr] = true;
    }

    function result(maybeEnum: any): maybeEnum is EnumClass[keyof EnumClass] {
        return !!reverseMapping[maybeEnum];
    }

    return result;
}
```

It works in TypeScript 4.2.4, but I have not tested earlier versions.

The main interesting part is the `EnumClass[keyof EnumClass]` return type. When such a type is an enum in TypeScript, it returns the original type of the enum where EnumClass is the type of the runtime enum class.

For an example of how to use this construction, suppose we have the following enum:

```
enum Direction {
    Left = "<-",
    Right = "->"
}
```

`Direction` is both a type as well as a runtime object. We can generate a type predicate for Direction and use it like so:

```
const isDirection = constructEnumPredicate(Direction);
function coerceDirection(maybeDir: string): Direction {
    // Since we make a type predicate rather than just a normal predicate,
    // no explicit type casting is necessary!
    return isDirection(maybeDir) ? maybeDir : Direction.Left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after. One question: what's the purpose of the `reverseMapping`?

Comment: @DavidGood that just makes it easier to convert into an existence check. You could also use a Set<string> or possibly even enumClass itself by checking if the input exists in the enumClass.

Answer (score 0):

If you there to find how to check union contain specific value, there is solution:

```
// source enum type
export const EMessagaType = {
   Info,
   Success,
   Warning,
   Error,
};

//check helper
const isUnionHasValue = <T extends number>(union: T, value: T) =>
   (union & value) === value;


//tests
console.log(
 isUnionHasValue(EMessagaType.Info | EMessagaType.Success), 
 EMessagaType.Success);

//output: true


console.log(
 isUnionHasValue(EMessagaType.Info | EMessagaType.Success), 
 EMessagaType.Error); 

//output: false
```

Answer (score -2):

```
enum ServicePlatform {
    UPLAY = "uplay",
    PSN = "psn",
    XBL = "xbl"
}
```

becomes:

```
{ UPLAY: 'uplay', PSN: 'psn', XBL: 'xbl' }
```

so

```
ServicePlatform.UPLAY in ServicePlatform // false
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
ServicePlatform.UPLAY.toUpperCase() in ServicePlatform // true
```

Comment: that only works because your keys and values in enum are the same text upper/lower case