# How to check does the given string exists as a value in a string enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

For example

```
enum ABC { A = "a", B = "bb", C = "ccc" };

alert("B" in ABC);  // true
alert("bb" in ABC); // false (i wanna true)
```

Please, keep in mind that we discuss about string enum features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if value exists in enum in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804805/check-if-value-exists-in-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly -- Unless I'm mistaken, that's not _exactly_ a duplicate, as TypeScript has different compilation logic for numeric and string enums. The solution proposed there wouldn't work here, see compiled output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your enum:

```
enum ABC {
    A = "a",
    B = "bb",
    C = "ccc"
};
```

Becomes this after compilation (at runtime):

```
var ABC = {
    A: "a",
    B: "bb",
    C: "ccc"
};
```

Therefore you need to check if any of the **values** in `ABC` is `"bb"`. To do this, you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(ABC).some(val => val === "bb"); // true
Object.values(ABC).some(val => val === "foo"); // false
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
enum ABC {
    A = "a",
    B = "bb",
    C = "ccc"
};
```

is compiled to the following JavaScript ([see demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20ABC%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20A%20%3D%20%22a%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20B%20%3D%20%22bb%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20C%20%3D%20%22ccc%22%0D%0A%7D%3B)):

```
var ABC;
(function (ABC) {
    ABC["A"] = "a";
    ABC["B"] = "bb";
    ABC["C"] = "ccc";
})(ABC || (ABC = {}));
```

This is why you are getting `true` for `"A" in ABC`, and `false` for `"bb" in ABC`. Instead, you need to look (i.e. loop) for values yourself; a short one liner could be this:

```
Object.keys(ABC).some(key => ABC[key] === "bb")
```

*(or you could iterate over values directly using `Object.values` if supported)*

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Object.values in typescript :(

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript 2016 or higher you can also use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for this purpose.

```js
Object.values(ABC).includes('bb' as ABC);
```

See also: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108791/5354201)