# Typescript: How to check if a value is a valid Enum key value?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get the name of an enum in typescript, like `nameof(FirstEnum)`? The following code has an ugly if switch that has to be expanded each time a new enum is defined. Is there a more generic way to achieve the same in typescript?

```
enum FirstEnum {
    First = 0,
    Second = 1,
    Third = 2,
}
enum SecondEnum {
    One,
    Two,
}


function translateEnum(type$, val): string {
    let lookupKey = '';
    if (type$ === FirstEnum) {
        lookupKey = `firstenum.${FirstEnum[val]}`;
    } else if (type$ === SecondEnum) {
        lookupKey = `secondenum.${SecondEnum[val]}`;
    } else {
        throw new Error('not supported');
    }
    //lookupkey example: secondenum.One
    const result = ''; //translate here, ex. await translationService.translate(lookupkey);
    return result;
}

translateEnum(SecondEnum , SecondEnum.One);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Typescript [`Enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are translated to JavaScript objects, you can check if `enum` key values are members of the `enums` using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator. Note that this only works for `enums` that are not `const` and are number-based.

```
enum FirstEnum {
    First = 0,
    Second = 1,
    Third = 2,
}
enum SecondEnum {
    One,
    Two,
}


function translateEnum(val: FirstEnum | SecondEnum): string {
    let lookupKey = '';
    if (val in FirstEnum || val in SecondEnum) {
      console.log(`Enum value ${val} is valid!`);
      //lookupkey example: secondenum.One
      const result = ''; //translate here, ex. await translationService.translate(lookupkey);
      return result;
    } else {
        console.log(`Enum value ${val} not supported.`);
        throw new Error('not supported');
    }
}

translateEnum(SecondEnum.One);

translateEnum(10);
```

## Output

```
Enum value 0 is valid!
Enum value 10 not supported.
Uncaught Error: not supported
    at translateEnum (eval at <anonymous> (main-0.js:804), <anonymous>:23:15)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main-0.js:804), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at main-0.js:804
```

## More Information

See stack**overflow** question [**Check if value exists in enum in TypeScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43804805/1164465).

Comment: IMHO the asker wants to get `"FirstEnum"` from the enum `FirstEnum`. I do not think that is possible though.

Comment: Tnx all for the support. I conclude from this answer that it is not possible to get rid of the if statement. I hope this feature will be added soon to typescript, if possible at all.