# How can I restrict values of a property in an object to values existing in an enum?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to restrict the values of a property based on values defined in an enum. I thought I could just do:

```
enum AcceptableValues {
  a = 0,
  b = 1,
  c = 2,
  d = 4,
}

interface Item {
  value: AcceptableValues
}

const x: Item = { value: 3 };
```

However, it seems that `3` is a valid value, even though it's not a value in the enum. How can I make it so that `3` would be invalid, but `0`, `1`, `2` and `4` are valid?

Comment: Is your real-world example using numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript enum as a parameter type allows invalid values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373640/typescript-enum-as-a-parameter-type-allows-invalid-values)

Comment: (Note if you used `AcceptableValues[name]` instead of the value it _would_ get checked - that's where enums are useful.)

Comment: You can create a type that accepts all the number literals in your enum. It would look like this: https://tsplay.dev/mL2OAw. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a type that "gets" the values of an enum as a union of literal types:

```
type EnumValues<E> = E extends number ? `${E}` extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never : E extends string ? `${E}` : never;
```

Since enum values can only be strings or numbers, that's all we have to cover here. If it's a number, we have to "stringify" the values, then convert them into numbers with [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types).

Then you'd use it like this:

```
interface Item {
  value: EnumValues<AcceptableValues>;
}
```

This also works for string enums, and enums that don't explicitly define values for their members (which are implicitly numbered, starting from 0).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxnYAHALgQwEYBtgDU1ZjADOUA3gLABQUUaUAvFAAwA01tGjUAjOzVDjcATP1oATbgBZ+AX2rUUATyTAoAUXAR8hEgB51APm7qowAB4pQ40lozAATlAD8UAAYASMutluzl61JPMgBLEAAzRygAOX8rEBsoO0dfFxioAC4k4AA3KKzTC3jE4hQHMIBzNOCfPyyQXMcAbgUqMKsHcLREKABJK2hKARyCIgKtHSJiPXhEVEwcSZJDFqp5Kmo4AHsQUqhzLP7gaCYyKBHdLIBmKFkmoA)

Comment: "type EnumValues<E> = E extends number ? `${E}` extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never : E extends string ? `${E}` : never;"

Wow.. that is... so... gross...

Is there really not a better way?

Comment: @patrick Like I said, that's because it's made to work for string enums as well. If you want only numbers, see Tobias's comment.