# Verify that a JSON object properties are contained in an Enum

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a Lambda HTTPS TS function that gets a JSON object passed to it from the Frontend. I wanted to do some validation on that JSON object

the body should have this shape (Notifications):

```
interface Notifications {
  type: NotificationType;
  frequency: FrequencyType;
}

enum NotificationType {
  SMS = 'SMS',
  EMAIL = 'EMAIL'
}

enum FrequencyType {
  INSTANT = 'INSTANT',
  DAILY = 'DAILY',
  WEEKLY = 'WEEKLY',
  NEVER = 'NEVER'
}
```

what I have now from another [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804805/check-if-value-exists-in-enum-in-typescript) is not working

```
  if (body && body.frequency in FrequencyType && body.type in NotificationType) {
//do stuff
}
```

is there a cleaner way to confirm that the Frontend would never pass a notification type that is not valid? I do use Typing on the FE but just trying to handle validation on the backend also

the TS to JS code complies down to this for the enums

```
   var NotificationType;

(function(NotificationType2) {

  NotificationType2["SMS"] = "SMS";

  NotificationType2["EMAIL"] = "EMAIL";

})(NotificationType || (NotificationType = {}));

var FrequencyType;

(function(FrequencyType2) {

  FrequencyType2["INSTANT"] = "INSTANT";

  FrequencyType2["DAILY"] = "DAILY";

  FrequencyType2["WEEKLY"] = "WEEKLY";

  FrequencyType2["NEVER"] = "NEVER";

})(FrequencyType || (FrequencyType = {}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS code

```
enum NotificationType {
  SMS = 'SMS',
  EMAIL = 'EMAIL'
}

enum FrequencyType {
  INSTANT = 'INSTANT',
  DAILY = 'DAILY',
  WEEKLY = 'WEEKLY',
  NEVER = 'NEVER'
}

type BodyType =  {
    frequency: NotificationType;
    type: NotificationType
}

const validate = (body:BodyType):boolean => !!body && body.frequency in FrequencyType && body.type in NotificationType;
```

After compile TS
validation code should works fine

```
validate({ frequency: 'INSTANT', type: 'SMS' }); // true
validate({}); // false
validate({ frequency: 'INSTANTS', type: 'SMS' }); // false
```

Check maybe you need OR condition.

```
!!body && (body.frequency in FrequencyType || body.type in NotificationType)
```

Answer (score 0):

so the frontend was passing in the the keys for the JSON object in the wrong case, also my //doStuff code was running a SQL PUT that was not working for this user because they did not have a record already in the DB so had to re-work that a bit