# How can I know at compile-time whether a type is an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to write a function that validates that a value is part of an enum, and throw if not. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755096/552510), I wrote:

```
    private ensureValueInEnum(enumType: any, value: string): void {
        if (!Object.values(enumType).includes(value)) {
            throw new Exception(`${value} is invalid value. Valid values are: ${Object.values(enumType).join(' / ')}`);
        }
    }
```

But, I don't like that enumType is `any`. Is there something I can write that says "enumType is an enum"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no.

Once compiled, there's nothing magic about enums. They are just objects with string keys and constant values. That type would be `Record<string, unknown>`.

So I think this type is as tight as your going to get:

```
function ensureValueInEnum(enumType: Record<string, unknown>, value: unknown): void {
  //
}
```

If you only want to support enums with string values, then you could do:

```
function ensureValueInEnum(enumType: Record<string, string>, value: string): void {
  //
}
```

But there no way to distinguish an enum from, say, this:

```
const testObj = {
    C: 'c',
    D: 'd',
}

ensureValueInEnum(testObj, 'c') // works
ensureValueInEnum(testObj, 'q') // error
```

If you want `testObj` to be a type error, and only enums declared with the `enum` keyword to be allowed, then I don't think that's possible.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=32&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAUFHUCCUAvFAOQCGJANNrgEJGkBGVmAvppgMYD2ISUiBIgDyjAFYMsuKAGEAXKU4tpAEQUkAJi3aYAZmBCdEAS15RQ8MACdgANTIAbMMACSIVJAAUoSDACeAA7ACgBKwDxWGgA8SFbGIADmlFAGANYg3ADuIAB8yQBujs4KaRnZAJQK+dzGGlBSuMa6UJ4AhKJi4YgAdIVOCN5o-kHl3fGcThoDfc7l5fU00jiIABZWWVAgwJlQyFbrVp4ABgAk6DPArFDG8NcgfbVQF91Q9g6PF7dkNgpnHV29IoDHwQYbAUZiGogTwkKAAelI5VYR3KAG5FlB2DoLNY7EC3B4IJ44EhCclyCRypgcTY3s4CWhiUIyaQAI6Ujg0vH9BleQRIDrkpRUrl01zuRn8kTicns8pAA)

Comment: Thanks. You say "Once compiled, there's nothing magic about enums" - I know, but I was hoping this was somehow expressible in compile-time. I guess not.